# XML & XSD validation error in browser

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm not really sure why the XML and XSD code are both showing error messages in the browser. I've tried to correct both based on the error but still nothing right

The XML in browser shows: "error on line 11 at column 16: Opening and ending tag mismatch: meta line 0 and head"

The XSD in browser shows: "error on line 31 at column 15: Opening and ending tag mismatch: element line 0 and all"

```js
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type = "text/xsl" href = "nutrition.xsl"?>
<nutrition:items xmlns:nutrition = "http://www.grandmascookies.com/nutrition">
<product name = "Grandma White's Cookies">
<item>
        <servingsize> 
                <amount> 1 </amount> 
                <unit> package </unit> 
                </servingsize>  
        <calories> 
                <amount> 260 </amount> 
                <unit> calories </unit> 
                </calories>
        <caloriesFat> 
                <amount> 100 </amount> 
                <unit> grams </unit> 
                </caloriesFat>   
                </item>
</product>
</nutrition:item>
```

```html
<?xml version = "1.0"?>

<schema xmlns = "http://wwww.w3.org/2001/XMLSCHEMA"
    xmlns:nutrition = "http://wwww.grandmascookies.com/nutrition"
    targetNamespace = "http://www.grandmascookies.com/nutrition">

    <simpleType name = "amount"> <restriction base = "int"/> </simpleType>
    <simpleType name = "unit"> <restriction base = "string"/> </simpleType>
  
    <complexType name = "nutritionFact">
        <all>
            <element name = "amount" type = "nutrition:amount"/>
            <element name = "unit" type = "nutrition:unit"/>
        </all>
    </complexType>
    
    <complexType name = "productType">
        <all>
            <element name = "product" type = "string">
            <element name = "servingsize" type = "nutrition:nutritionFact"/>
            <element name = "calories" type = "nutrition:nutritionFact"/>
            <element name = "caloriesFat" type = "nutrition:nutritionFact"/>
            </all>
    </complexType>
    
    <complexType name = "productType1">
            <element name = "item" type = "nutrition:productType"/> 
            <element name = "items" type = "nutrition:productType1"/>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

Comment: Start tag `nutrition:items`, end tag `nutrition:item`

Comment: `element` have no `/` at the end.

Comment: Use any xml-editor. It shows you all errors.

Comment: elements should or shouldn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the comments, and you really should use an XML parser, but to be explicit:

In the XML file the last line should be

```
</nutrition:items>
```

Note: item**s** not item

In the XSD file the third line in the definition

```
<complexType name = "productType">
```

should be

```
<element name = "product" type = "string"/>
```

Note: `/>`at the end not just `>`.